# Replace variable later in code? (this is the kind of topic I dont know how to search for)

Tags: java, string, replace

First off here is the code with the appropriate descriptions for each command. (Note: the last line is what gives the code error and what I need help fixing).

What is happening on the last line of the code pertains to my question. how is the 'fullName' variable going to be changed to uppercase when it already has an input inside it. how do I go about replacing it later in the code? Thank you

```
import java.util.Scanner; // Needed for the Scanner class

public class NumericTypes {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        //TASK #2 Create a Scanner object here

        //Reading from system.in
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 

        //prompt user for first name
        System.out.println("Enter your first name: "); 

        //scans the next input as a double
        String firstName = keyboard.nextLine(); 

        //prompt user for last name
        System.out.println("Enter your last name: "); 

        //scans the next input as a double
        String lastName = keyboard.nextLine(); 

        //concatenate the user's first and last names
        String fullName = (firstName + " " + lastName);

        //print out the user's full name
        System.out.println(fullName);

        //task 3 starts here
        //get first initial from variable 'fullName'
        char firstinitial = fullName.charAt(0);
        System.out.println("the first initial is: " + firstinitial);



        //use the 'toUpperCase' method to change fullName variable to caps
        // and store into the fullName variable
        String fullName = fullName.toUpperCase()
   }
}
```

Comment: You forgot `;`.

Comment: Your program shouldn't run due to syntax error and compilation error because there are two variables with the same name (fullName).

Comment: The **fullName** variable is already declared earlier on. Remove the **String** declaration and yes....place the semi-colon at the end of your code line.

Comment: Keep in mind that `String` is `immutable` in Java.

So fullName will be created as a new `String` with uppercase, and replaced when this call happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to create the variable `fullName` which already exists. Change the variable name to something else.

```
String upperFullName = fullName.toUpperCase();
```

or omit the declaration

```
fullName = fullName.toUpperCase();
```

Comment: exactly.. from my limited research this comment made the most sense, but I thought there was something missing.. I defer to this comment on my homework assignment 

"3. Use the toUpperCase method to change the fullName to all capitals and store it back into the fullName variable" 

the above quote is what my assignment wanted me to do but it implies that it can replace the 'fullname' variable later on in the code even though the 'fullname' variable is a combination of the 'firstname' and 'lastname' variable.

Comment: basically, the way my assignment instructs me, its heavily implying that strings can be changed subsequently in code. which is a bit frustrating since this is an entry level course.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an error, change

```
String fullName = fullName.toUpperCase()
```

to

```
fullName = fullName.toUpperCase();
```

First off, you didn't write a semicolon `;` at the end of the statement.

Second, you can't declare two variables with the same name, which you were doing here. Removing `String` from this sentence *changes* the value of the variable `fullName`.

Comment: oops. I pretty much just posted the same answer. I'll delete it. Sorry about that.

Comment: thank you for the clarification (the semicolon was just a rookie mistake). Im very entry level in java so I was unaware of that